# Two Table Views in One VC

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, swift4

I want to display two (or more) table views from a single view controller. I mean display *simultaneously*, e.g.,  beside each other or one above the other. The only way I can think of doing it is with child view controllers. Is there a better or easier way?

Thanks for your comments.

Comment: it is possible to do it, it is pretty much a valid situation, but what are your problems with it? how do you define _better_ or _easier_? it would be great if you can present something first about your idea / concept – because currently this question is primarily opinion based atm.

Answer (score 1):

Yes of course you can use like this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell 
{
    if tableView == firstTableView
    {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell1", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Section \(indexPath.section) Row \(indexPath.row)"
            return cell
    }
    else if (tableView == secondTableView)
    {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell2", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Section \(indexPath.section) Row \(indexPath.row)"
            return cell
    }
    else
    {
        return UITableViewCell()
    }
}
```

Similar to other tableview delegate methods, you should add a condition for each table

Answer (score 0):

If your use case is to have two individually scrolling table views then you can simply add two table views in the xib, assign datasource and delegates and call it a day.

If your use case is to display two types of information on a page I'd recommend using just one table view and handling what to display manually.

Let me know if you need any more help.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Switch Condition**

---

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    switch tableView {
    case firsttableView:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
        cell.label1.text = "Zaid"
        cell.label2.text = "Ahamd"
        return cell
    case secondTableView:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SecondTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! SecondTableViewCell
        cell.labelText.text = "ZaidAfzalMughal"
        return cell
    default:
        print("Something wrong")
    }
    return cell

}
```